# Pre-select and update Angular Material Selection List

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I a component with a selection list (checkboxes with each list item) using Angular Material. I can't figure out how to set the checkboxes before the list is displayed and then get the selected items following user interaction....i.e. I want the items to be pre-selected if a user has previously selected them, and once they update their selection I want to keep the update so once they refresh them have the values pre-selected.
Here is the setup:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/material-selection-list-5-0-0?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts
How do to keep my updated selections and show them as pre-selected?

Comment: You can save this info in your database, local storage, you need to be more specific

Comment: @TheUnreal, i save the info in the database and have a GET endpoint which returns {
    "taskTypeAreas": [
        {
            "name": "Area1"
        },
        {
            "name": "Area2"
        }    
    ]
}

So how do extract and pre-select the returned values in the UI :)

Comment: you can use the localstorage like that 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/material-selection-list-5-0-0-sdkpt5?file=app/app.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

If you already get the information from your DB you can just update your `selectedOptions` array.

If this is what you got from the server:

```
this.yourDataFromServer = { "taskTypeAreas": [ { "name": "Area1" }, { "name": "Area2" } ] };
```

You can just create a new array with the area strings:

```
this.selectedOptions = this.yourDataFromServer.taskTypeAreas.map((area) => area.name);
```

It should work since you already defined the `selectedOptions` as ngModel of your mat list.

Comment: Thank you :)  here's my service console log :Response: { "taskTypeAreas": [ { "name": "Area1" }, { "name": "Area2" } ] };
and on NgOninit i did 
this.selectedOptions = this.yourDataFromServer.taskTypeAreas.map((area) => area.name);
i get ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined.